# Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database + mysql + hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to use Hibernate and mysql in Eclipse

error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired
> from the underlying database! at
> com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106) at
> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
> at
> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
> at
> org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:56)
> at
> org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
> ... 53 more Caused by:
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A
> ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or
> source. at
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
> at
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
> at
> com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
> at
> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
> ... 56 more

Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Test?useSSL=false;"</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">false</property>
        <property name="use_sql_comments">false</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>

        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>

        <mapping class="com.test.model.Book"></mapping>
        
        
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: You''ve already got a question open on this

Comment: I closed that question @g00se